# is the google AIY voice kit version 1 compatible with the raspberry pi 4b

Tags: pi-4

I want to get a raspberry pi and I already have multiple projects in mind so I don't want to spend too much money on each project so I found a AIY voice kit v1 on ebay for 14 dollars AUD (with a money back guarantee if its a scam) and was wondering if the AIY voice kit v1 would work with the raspberry pi model 4 b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment due to low reputation, so I am posting here.

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian/issues/645) in GitHub, I believe you can make it work as someone also shared [customized image](https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian/releases/tag/v20191113) that supports your kit.